# How to read full line while using line split?

Tags: java, split, reader

```
BufferedReader tableRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tableFile));   
while ((tableLine = tableRead.readLine()) != null){
            cNameData = tableLine.split(",");
            for (int i =0; i< cNameData.length; i++){
                System.out.println(cNameData[i]);
            }
        }
```

This code in mind takes a line for example, John, 23, Male, and splits it and puts it into the array cNameData, but when it prints out it gives 23 and Male only, how do I insert john also into the array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems fine.

Comment: If the line is of the format John, 23, Male, John should be in the array cNameData  at index position 0

Comment: I print it and it just returns 23 and Male, not John for some reason, which is weird since i'm pretty sure it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the line it reads?

Comment: Yes, the line itself when I print it comes out normally, but when I print using the split is when the problem arises where the first string before the split isnt recognized.